# Запрос ss = df.query('@x in name and year_of_release == @n').index возвращает пустой фрейм

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных, nan

```
RangeIndex: 16715 entries, 0 to 16714
Data columns (total 11 columns):
name               16713 non-null object
platform           16715 non-null object
year_of_release    16446 non-null float64
genre              16713 non-null object
na_sales           16715 non-null float64
eu_sales           16715 non-null float64
jp_sales           16715 non-null float64
other_sales        16715 non-null float64
critic_score       8137 non-null float64
user_score         10014 non-null object
rating             9949 non-null object
dtypes: float64(6), object(5)
memory usage: 1.4+ MB
None
```

Хочу подставить год в `year_of_release`, если в нем `NaN` и в `name` входит год.

Пишу цикл:

```
    n = np.nan
    for year in range(2000, 2018):
        x = str(year)
        ss = df.query('@x in name and year_of_release == @n').index
        df.loc[ss, 'year_of_release'] = year - 1
```

Запрос `ss` выдает пустой список индексов. Хотя доподлинно известно, есть в названиях года и в тех же строках есть значения `NaN` столбце годов.

Например, вот такая строка:

```
name             platform     year_of_release
Madden NFL 2004  PS2                      NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще один вариант:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
              name platform  year_of_release
0  Madden NFL 2004      PS2              NaN
1              NFL      PS2           2017.0

In [37]: res = df.loc[df["name"].str.contains("NFL") & df["year_of_release"].isna()].index

In [38]: res
Out[38]: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 4):

"Прелесть" `NaN` в том, что он не равен самому себе, поэтому сравнение `column == NaN` не сработает:

```
In [73]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[73]: False
```

Но этим же фактом можно воспользоваться себе на пользу, т.к. единственной причиной когда значение в столбце не равно самому себе это когда это значение `NaN`:

```
ss = df.query('@x in name and year_of_release != year_of_release').index
# --------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Т.е.

```
df.query('year_of_release != year_of_release')
```

эквивалентно следующему условию в SQL:

```
WHERE year_of_release IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо! С этим понятно теперь, а вот такой запрос тоже не дает результатов ss = df.query('@x in name').index

Comment: @ДаниилЕрмошин, Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)